# Deleting column/field in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes, delete

How to remove or delete column fields in a shapefile using PyQGIS?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you get no joy with QGSVectorLayer::deleteAttribute as they docs say: *delete an attribute field (but does not commit it)* have a look at the data provider. As QGIS deals with lots of feature types with different drivers I suspect that it's left up to the driver as to whether or not a field can be deleted.

Here's some code that I dredged up that may help:

```
fields = vlayer.dataProvider().fields()

count = 0
for name, field in fields.iteritems():
    if field.name() == fieldName:
        return count
    count += 1
```

To get the index of the field from the name. In this case I'm not using `.upper()` but I would recommend it.

After getting the index of the field you (might) delete it using the dataprovider.

```
fList = list()
fList.append(count)
vlayer.dataProvider().deleteAttributes(fList)
```

It's expecting a list so the integer needs to be put into a list. I have not used this method; normally I would use ArcMap to delete the field.

As pointed out by RogerHuang, the [fields of the layer may need to be updated](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a2a3b5542fc9714a405f68b0afca4a963) now that they have been changed to refresh the layers' fields definition:

```
vlayer.updateFields()
```

Comment: vLayer.fieldNameIndex('YourFieldName') might be a easier way to get index

Comment: Thanks @vinayan, I have overlooked that one. The code I took this from is quite old, that function may be newer than my code.

Comment: Thanks, It worked well  Is there way to get max. index number ? I have an error "return outside function" Thanks for answers

Comment: Thanks for answers all of my problems solved and I combined ideas to find max. field index by following ways            count = layer.dataProvider().attributeIndexes()
print count
maxindex = count[-1]
print maxindex

Comment: layer.updateFields() seems to be needed, in order to regenerate fields from data provider. https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html

Answer (score 12):

For **PyQGIS 3** this might be the easiest way to delete a **single field**:

```py
# Get a layer object and enter edit mode:
my_vectorlayer = iface.activeLayer()
with edit(my_vectorlayer):
    # Get the field index by its name:
    my_field = my_vectorlayer.fields().indexFromName('name of field you want to delete')
    # Delete the field by its index, note that it has to be in a list:
    my_vectorlayer.dataProvider().deleteAttributes([my_field])
# Update the fields, so the changes are recognized:
my_vectorlayer.updateFields()
```

Or if you want to **delete multiple fields at once**, you can go for this slightly modified:

```py
# Get a layer object:
my_vectorlayer = iface.activeLayer()
# Create a list of the fieldnames you want to delete:
fieldnames_to_delete = ['field_a','field_c']
# Enter Edit mode
with edit(my_vectorlayer):
    # Create empty list we will fill with the fieldindexes
    fields_to_delete = []
    # Iterate over the list of fieldnames and get the indexes
    for fieldname_to_delete in fieldnames_to_delete:
        # Get the field index by its name:
        fieldindex_to_delete = my_vectorlayer.fields().indexFromName(fieldname_to_delete)
        # You can also check if the field exists
        if fieldindex_to_delete == -1:
            # If it does not exist, just skip it and go to the next one. This may prevent a crash or error :)
            continue
        # Append the index to the list
        fields_to_delete.append(fieldindex_to_delete)
    # Delete the fields by their indexes, note that it has to be a list:
    my_vectorlayer.dataProvider().deleteAttributes(fields_to_delete)
# Update the fields, so the changes are recognized:
my_vectorlayer.updateFields()
```

Comment: what do i need to do if i want to delete multiple fields by name?

Comment: thank you very much!!

Answer (score 9):

There's several methods but I will mention the ones I normally use, both using the **Python Console**.

---

### For SINGLE shapefiles:

- Method 1 - Using a method utilising the QGIS algorithm - *Delete Column*:

  ```
  output_0=processing.runalg('qgis:deletecolumn', myshapefile.shp, "myFirstField", None)
  output_1=processing.runalg('qgis:deletecolumn', output_0['OUTPUT'], "mySecondField", None)
  output_2=processing.runalg('qgis:deletecolumn', output_1['OUTOUT'], "myThirdField", myoutput.shp)
  ```
- Method 2 - Deleting the fields directly by selecting the layer from the *Layers* window (Table of Contents) and using the following code:

  ```
  layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()              # Sets the selected layer as the active layer
  res = layer.dataProvider().deleteAttributes([0])    # The [0] represents the 1st field, so [1] is the 2nd field etc. To delete multiple fields, use the comma to separate. Eg. [0, 2, 4]
  layer.updateFields()                                # Updates the layer with the changes
  ```

---

### For MULTIPLE shapefiles:

- Following on from Method 1, you can use the following script which was tested with 2 folders on the Desktop - *"Testing"* (which contained the shapefiles) and *"Results"* (which will contain the output shapefiles of the script):

  ```
  import processing, os, glob

  from os.path import expanduser
  home = expanduser("~")

  result_path = home + "\Desktop\Results\\"
  os.chdir(home + "\Desktop\Testing\\")

  for fname in glob.glob("*.shp"):
      output_0=processing.runalg('qgis:deletecolumn', fname, "myFirstField", None)
      output_1=processing.runalg('qgis:deletecolumn', output_0['OUTPUT'], "mySecondField", None)
      output_2=processing.runalg('qgis:deletecolumn', output_1['OUTPUT'], "myThirdField", result_path + fname)

  print "All done!"
  ```
- Following on from Method 2, you can use the following code if you have multiple shapefiles loaded in your *Layers* window **without** having to select them individually.

  ```
  for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
      res = layer.dataProvider().deleteAttributes([0])
      layer.updateFields()
  ```

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've done as you suggested in the 1st method but appeared this comment: "Error: Wrong parameter value: None". I can´t use the 2nd method because I have to do the same for a large number of shapefiles, about 8000. Any idea?