# QGIS models. deleting multiple columns is slow, is there a better way?

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I have a process that has lots of items.  This for some reason seems to make a difference to the time it takes to drop a column from a shapefile during a model run.

I need to drop MANY columns. QGIS spends a long time on the 1st, the same time on the 2nd, then the 3rd... Is there any way to drop many columns in one go or even better just 'hide them' so the final output only take the ones it needs?

Comment: Personally, I prefer running commands through the _Python Console_ than a model as I did find model runs to be quite slow in comparison. But this could just be me. Perhaps the following post might help: [How to delete column/field in PyQGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109078/how-to-delete-column-field-in-pyqgis)?

Answer (score 4):

Try Advanced Processing Toolbox --> QGIS --> Vector Table tools --> Refactor fields

This can be called in modeler or pyqgis as well. I usually run this as a first step in the model to get rid of unnecessary fields and then at the end to remove any working fields that aren't required.