# Delete all fields with the string "RAWI" using QGIS Python

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I would like to delete all fields with the string "RAWI". For instance the field "RAWI_WA" and the field "RAWI_BO" should be deleted but not the field "NSG_RAW"

Comment: Does this answer help? http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/109078/43

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following code in the **Python console** which, for your selected layer, deletes all fields which contains `RAWI` in the field name:

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
# Get field names of layer
field_names = [field.name() for field in layer.fields()]

# Use `with edit()` method to edit and commit changes in one go
with edit(layer):
    # Assign count in reverse order for each field which will be used as index
    for i, j in reversed(list(enumerate(field_names))):
        if "RAWI" in j:
            layer.deleteAttribute(i)
```

Comment: Lovely use of enumerate to get the index and item.

Comment: @RichardMorgan - Thank you :) I'm sure there's a nicer way of getting the indices for the relevant fields!

Comment: `layer.startEdiging()` and `layer.commitChanges()` do nothing if the nested calls are on the dataprovider. rather use `layer.deleteAttribute(idx)` instead. And if you want to have it extra-nice you can use `with edit(layer)` instead :) (reference: http://www.opengis.ch/2015/08/12/with-edit-layer/)

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn - Thank you =). I've used the `with edit(layer):` method as you suggested, however I seem to be having issues with `layer.deleteAttribute()`. If I put this inside the `if` loop, it only deletes half of the fields each time the code is run. Guess I missed something... ;)

Comment: That's probably caused by the indexes changing while removing fields. Better iterate in reverse order. And still, if using `startEditing()` or `with edit` don't use `dataProvider()` at all - or skip the `startEditing()` / `with edit` part ;)

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn - Ahh you're a genius! Many thanks for your valuable lesson :)

Comment: One last hint: use `layer.fields()` (or for older qgis versions `layer.pendingFields()`) or you may have troubles with joined and virtual fields.

Comment: I tried the `with edit(layer):` in the console and it worked great.   It does not seem to work in a plugin.  Does anyone know what is missing for the plugin?