# PyQGIS: looping over shapefile's fields to rename them using substring

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes, pyqgis-3

I'm trying to rename multiple field names (about 150) of a shapefile in QGIS. Their names are different but they all end by `_xf20` and I would like to remove this part for each of them.

I've looked up to other topics that could help and I've found this one: [Rename fields of shapefile using PyQGIS 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317223/rename-fields-of-shapefile-using-pyqgis-3) with the code:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

# Open editing session
layer.startEditing()

# Rename field
for field in layer.fields():
    if field.name() == 'oldName':
        idx = layer.fields().indexFromName(field.name())
        layer.renameAttribute(idx, 'newName')

# Close editing session and save changes
layer.commitChanges()
```

and this one: [Delete all fields with the string "RAWI" using QGIS Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187116/delete-all-fields-with-the-string-rawi-using-qgis-python)

But even if it is a start, I'm a beginner with Python and I don't find a way to adapt them for my case.

I would rather not edit every single field manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work by slicing your old field names to return everything before the last 5 characters'_xf20' which you want to remove.

While I have tested this in QGIS 3.14.15 and it worked fine for me, please make a backup copy of your shapefile first just in case something goes wrong.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

layer.startEditing()

for field in layer.fields():
    if field.name().startswith('Z10'):
        idx = layer.fields().lookupField(field.name())
        new_name = field.name()[:-5]
        layer.renameAttribute(idx, new_name)

layer.commitChanges()
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much for your help Ben, your answer works perfectly !!!
Also I was wondering if there was an easy way to only rename fields starting by "Z10" for example ? I tried adding `if layer.name().startswith('Z10')` to your script but it doesn't work (even thought I don't get any error message)

Comment: @Linda, I have edited my answer. By the way, if my answer worked for you could please accept it with the check mark?