# Deleting the same column(s) from different shapefiles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, fields-attributes, batch, delete

In QGIS, I have a problem deleting the same column out of different shapefiles, is there a way to do this?

I want to delete several columns out of all these layers, is there a way to do this without opening each individual attribute table and manually selecting the fields

[image: example]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A PyQGIS solution. Tested on QGIS 3.24.1-Tisler.

Proceed with `Plugins > Python Console > Show Editor` and paste one of the scripts below.

The press `Run script` [image: run script] and get the output.

#### This approach will directly modify the existing layer

Partially inspired from @MrXsquared's deleted answer.

```py
selected_layers = iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers()
# otherwise use a manual input
# layers_names = ['layer_1', 'layer_2']
# selected_layers = [QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(f'{name}')[0] for name in layers_names]

columns_to_delete = ['top','bottom']

if len(selected_layers):
    for layer in selected_layers:
        columns_to_delete_indx = [layer.fields().indexFromName(column) for column in columns_to_delete if column in layer.fields().names()]
        if len(columns_to_delete_indx):
            layer.startEditing()
            layer.dataProvider().deleteAttributes(columns_to_delete_indx)
            layer.commitChanges()
```

Before:
[image: input]

After:
[image: result]

#### This approach will only create a temporary layer from the existing layer

Another option is to use the ["Drop field(s)"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#drop-field-s) geoalgorithm via `"native:deletecolumn"`.

```py
selected_layers = iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers()
columns_to_delete = ['top','bottom']

if len(selected_layers):
    for layer in selected_layers:
        processing.runAndLoadResults("native:deletecolumn",
            {'COLUMN' : columns_to_delete,
            'INPUT' : layer,
            'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
```

---

**References:**

- [Deleting column/field in PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109078/how-to-delete-column-field-in-pyqgis)
- [PyQGIS Developer Cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/index.html)