# Delete fields/attributes from QgsVectorLayer (PyQGIS)

Tags: pyqgis

UPDATE 2
Again I updated the code according to this: https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#modifying-vector-layers-with-an-editing-buffer. But now I have a again the problem, that no field is deleted. My code:

```
            dlayer = QgsVectorLayer(filename, 'layer_name', 'ogr')
            fieldnames = [field.name() for field in dlayer.fields()]
            print(len(fieldnames))
            dlayer.startEditing()
            dlayer.deleteAttributes([1])
            dlayer.commitChanges()
            fieldnamesUpdated = [field.name() for field in dlayer.fields()]
            print(len(fieldnamesUpdated))
```

---

UPDATE
I updated the code according to the suggestions, but I still get the assertion error. This is the error: `File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.3\apps\qgis\python\qgis\core\additions\edit.py", line 38, in __enter__ assert self.layer.startEditing() AssertionError`.

This is my code now, what am I still doing wrong?

```
def deleteFields(path):
    xml_list_paths = []

    for file in os.listdir(path):
        # make sure to only get the files with certain type, e.g. '.shp'
        if 'xml' in file:
            filename = f'{path}\{file}'
            # print(filename)
            xml_list_paths.append(filename)

            dlayer = QgsVectorLayer(filename, 'layer_name', 'ogr')

            # Create a list of the fieldnames you want to delete:
            fieldnames_to_delete = [field.name() for field in dlayer.fields()]
            # Enter Edit mode
            with edit(dlayer):
                # Create empty list we will fill with the fieldindexes
                fields_to_delete = []
                # Iterate over the list of fieldnames and get the indexes
                for fieldname_to_delete in fieldnames_to_delete:
                    # Get the field index by its name:
                    fieldindex_to_delete = dlayer.fields().indexFromName(fieldname_to_delete)
                    # You can also check if the field exists
                    if fieldindex_to_delete == -1:
                        # If it does not exist, just skip it and go to the next one. This may prevent a crash or error :)
                        continue
                    # Append the index to the list
                    fields_to_delete.append(fieldindex_to_delete)
                # Delete the fields by their indexes, note that it has to be a list:
                dlayer.dataProvider().deleteAttributes(fields_to_delete)
            # Update the fields, so the changes are recognized:
            dlayer.updateFields()
```

---

---

I have multiple (~4000) xml-files, which I want to merge. As I stumpled about a length-problem of a certain field, when trying to merge, and I only need the geometry of the objects, I would like to first remove all the attributes (or 'fields') from the files.

I tried to create script which should delete a field (as an example) but it seems to do literally nothing:

```
def mergeXMLFiles(path):


    for file in os.listdir(path):

        if 'xml' in file:
            filename = f'{path}\{file}'


            
            # create Qgis-Vector layer 
            dlayer = QgsVectorLayer(filename, 'layer_name', 'ogr')

            # Create list from all field names and count 
            listoffields = [field.name() for field in dlayer.fields()]
            print(len(listoffields))
            
            # Delete the field with index 1 as an Example
            # and update the fields
            dlayer.dataProvider().deleteAttributes([1])
            dlayer.updateFields()

            # Create again a list of all fields in the layer and print
            # the count of the field names
            updatedlistoffields = [field.name() for field in dlayer.fields()]
            print(len(updatedlistoffields))
```

The second list should have less fields than the first list, but it doesn't, so I guess the deletion , so the code

```
            dlayer.dataProvider().deleteAttributes([1])
            dlayer.updateFields()
```

doesnt delete the field with index 1.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your layer is not in edit mode

Comment: @MrXsquared's comment is the correct answer. You can either apply `layer.startEditing()` + `layer.commitChanges()` or `edit(layer)`. See this article for more details: https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/pyqgis101-creating-editing-a-new-vector-layer/. Moreover, I would like to close this question, because it is a duplicate of this one https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109078/deleting-column-field-in-pyqgis.

Comment: Before the code above I tried layer.startEditing() and it threw me an error, which, when I read about, needed refactoring the layer. So I searched for another solution. I will try it again and come back to give feedback

Comment: @Taras I had a look at https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/pyqgis101-creating-editing-a-new-vector-layer/, but it doesn't say how to delete attrubutes, but how to add them

Comment: Putting the layer in edit mode is not needed if working directly with `dataProvider()` methods (no edit buffer). In fact, it is not recommended to mix `QgsVectorLayer` and `QgsVectorDataProvider` editing methods. Firstly you should `print(dlayer.dataProvider().capabilitiesString())` to see if "Delete Attributes" is printed. If not, then deleting attributes is not supported by the data provider. Otherwise add more info (e.g. a sample) of the structure of your .xml files

Comment: See [Modifying Vector Layers](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#modifying-vector-layers) and [Adding and Removing Fields](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#adding-and-removing-fields)

Comment: @Ben W Thanks for helping!  The function deleteAttributes() is supported. In the meantime I updated my code in the question, but it still doesn't work.... And I just see, that you ```QgsVectorLayer ``` and ```edit``` doesn't work together.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting column/field in PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109078/deleting-column-field-in-pyqgis)

Comment: Unfortunately no,  I tried that code and have included it in my question (under UPDATE)

Comment: Could you check if layer is valid? e.g. `print(dlayer.isValid())`
I guess, QGIS does not recognize your xml structure as a valid layer.

Comment: When I print the dlayer.isValid() I get 'True'

Comment: Please share your file. It will be hard to go further without that.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share the file, as the data is sensitive. I'm trying at the moment another method as I have a bit of a time pressure. I will first convert the files to gpkg as with that format I have more options to work on them as I have more toolings for that format (e.g. geopandas, and I guess also pyqgis may work with that file format better ... I hope).

Comment: Effectively, that's a solution to work on a copy of your data after converting to a format that is easier to handle. gpkg is a good candidate to work with pyqgis.